# Possible bug with high "3D view far clipping distance"

Tags: 3d-view

I think I have encountered a Blender bug. In the default scene (lamp set at "sun") I have set the 3D view far clipping distance at 10000. Now I cannot rotate the sun lamp anymore. Do you agree ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your .blend file the light source is set to Point not Sun.That's why You don't see direction line.